# using logstash to sync data

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to use logstash to sync all my data on my MySql server to my Elasticsearch server.

I've aleardy learned the basics of logstash.conf, this is my file:

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost/homestead"
        jdbc_user => "homestead"
        jdbc_password => "secret"
        jdbc_driver_library => "/home/vagrant/Code/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        statement => "SELECT * from volunteer"
    }
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost/homestead"
        jdbc_user => "homestead"
        jdbc_password => "secret"
        jdbc_driver_library => "/home/vagrant/Code/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        statement => "SELECT * from contact"
    }

} 
output {
    elasticsearch {
        document_id => "%{uid}"
        hosts => "localhost"
    } 
}
```

**My intention is to copy every table into a Type. How do I specify this?**

edit: "type" instead of "index"
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean every table in **its own index**?

Comment: No, I was confused, sorry.
Every table has to go into it's own "type" into 1 index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is simply to add a field (using `add_field`) in each input denoting the type name which you want the data to be indexed in and then use that variable as the type name in the `elasticsearch` output.

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost/homestead"
        jdbc_user => "homestead"
        jdbc_password => "secret"
        jdbc_driver_library => "/home/vagrant/Code/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        statement => "SELECT * from volunteer"
        add_field => {"type" => "volunteer"}
    }
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost/homestead"
        jdbc_user => "homestead"
        jdbc_password => "secret"
        jdbc_driver_library => "/home/vagrant/Code/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        statement => "SELECT * from contact"
        add_field => {"type" => "contact"}
    }
} 
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost"]
        index => "homestead"
        document_type => "%{type}"             <--- specify the index here
        document_id => "%{uid}"
    } 
}
```

Be aware though that using the same index to host several different mapping types might lead to type conflicts. The short story is that two different fields with the same name in two different types MUST ALWAYS have the same type definition. Read more about it [in this blog article](https://www.elastic.co/blog/index-vs-type)

Comment: Yes, this seems like what I need!

Comment: let us know how it goes for you, but I'm pretty sure you'd be better off indexing each of your tables into a different index.

Comment: Can you explian why it would be better to index each of my tables into a different index?

Comment: Exactly for the reasons I mentioned at the end of my answer. Ultimately, it depends on your data schema, but if you're going to put all your data into different types of the same index, you need to make sure that all fields that have the same name MUST also have the same type definition.